# How do I install a Ruby gem from GitHub and have it work in IRB?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Seems like every Ruby tutorial I find centers around Rails.

Anyway, I simply want to install a gem from a GitHub repo and have that gem work in irb.

I want to install the `exifr` gem.  When I do a `gem install exifr` it doesn't get the newest version.

So I created a `Gemfile` and put:

```
gem 'exifr', :git => 'git://github.com/remvee/exifr.git'
```

Then `bundle install`.  Installs OK but now `gem list` doesn't find the gem.  So I can't require it in irb.

Any help for NON Rails applications?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to kick off the bundler setup if you want to use the gems from a gemfile:

```
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'exifr'
```

or:

```
irb -rbundler/setup
> require 'exifr'
```

This is equivalent to running `bundle exec irb`, except it doesn't depend on a specific invocation to work, and instead presumes that a Gemfile is available and the gems were installed with Bundler.

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
bundle exec gem list
```

And..

```
bundle exec irb -rexifr
```

And see if that works.  That should help gem/irb find the installed gem.